# Open file securely with an external Android application without copying the file onto the external storage

Tags: android, security, file-io, android-sdcard

I'm doing a secure application, where an user can browse some file and open them with application presents on the phone. So for now, my application is really secure, files are well encrypted, but I have one MAJOR break. Indeed, I'm using my application to open the user secure files which are of different types (pdf, doc, txt, jpg, ...) so I'm using the external application presents on the user phone to open them. But my issue is here, because to let another application to open these files, I need to provide an Android storage location to the application that I want to use.

Here is the code that I'm using right now:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
File fileToOpen = new File(activity.getExternalCacheDir().getAbsolutePath() + 
    "/" + fileName);

MimeTypeMap mime = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton();
String extension = fileToOpen.getName().substring(
        fileToOpen.getName().lastIndexOf(".") + 1);
String type = mime.getMimeTypeFromExtension(extension);
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);

intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(fileToOpen), type);

Manager.getActivity().startActivityForResult(intent,
        ExplorerActivity.FILE_CLOSED_SUCCESSFULLY);
```

So, as you can see in my code, I need to store my real file into the cache directory to open it, so if a thief has an access to the user phone, it can open real files presents into this directory so my application is not secure anymore.
Of course I'm deleting this plain file right after the user has closed it and I have encrypted it, but the deletion doesn't mean that the file is totally deleted from the phone. Before deletion, I'm rewriting with some null byte but it's not enough for a secure deltion of this file.

So now, what I want from you it's an idea to achieve what I want to do: open a file without storing it into the Android hard storage.

Here are some leads that I had:

- Open the file with my own app (but it's a lot to implement because there are too many types of files, and I really don't like to develop something which exists already)
- Find a solution to open the file without storing it externally of my application (What I mean is to open the file directly with the byte array of this file)
- Store the file into the phone RAM (I don't know if it is possible)

So this is a non-exhaustive list and any other suggestion will be appreciated. And if you can provide any help about one of the solution that I have proposed, please don't hesitate. Don't hesitate also to tell me if one of my ideas are completely impossible or wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried your own `contentProvider` which overrides `openFile` , so files that are private to your app are opened by you and you return `filedescriptor` which is accessible to other apps

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I will check this lead right now and keep you inform about the result.

Comment: I have one question about your proposed solution. If I'm well understanding the contentProvider concept, you need to create a shared database where I will put my sensitive file. But is this database is secured? What I mean it's, is there a way for a thief to retrieve data from this database just by reading the phone hard drive?

Comment: you dont need a database. For your contentprovider dont implement update, query , delete methods, just implement file open method. So just like you pass file uri you pass your own contentprovider uri. So its as safe as your file. But you can never guarantee security from a rooted phone

Comment: While it may be possible to implement `openFile()` in a way that does not require an actual file in the filesystem, I have yet to find an example of doing so.

Comment: Nandeesh ok thanks
@CommonsWare Ok, but do you think that I could use another way to do what I want? If not, I will try to be the first to implement openFile() method without a file into the fileSystem.

Comment: @grattmandu03: The `ContentProvider`-without-a-file approach that this answer focuses on is the closest that I have come. There is a `MemoryFile` that Android uses internally for this sort of thing, but it is not part of the SDK. I thought I had filed an issue to get `MemoryFile` opened up, but apparently I had not, so I filed a new one just now: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=37372 The only other approach that I can think of would be to use a socket and get a `FileDescriptor` for that, but then anything could connect to the socket while it is open.

Comment: Ok thanks to both of you, I will try these possibilities and keep you inform of my different results.

Comment: @CommonsWare i had not known about memoryfile. I searched it and ParcelFileDescriptor does have a deprecated and non public [api](http://androidxref.com/4.0.4/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/os/ParcelFileDescriptor.java#235) which can create pfd using data backed by a memoryfile. Not sure why its not exposed.  ParcelFileDescriptor.createpipe looks a better option as it gives a write pipe and a read pipe and might be secure too

Comment: @nandeesh: I could not figure out how to use those pipes. If you work up a sample, I'd love to see it.

Comment: @CommonsWare I created a sample app. Its [here](https://github.com/nandeeshwar/Pfd-Create-Pipe) . i am opening an image on network location and passing through pipes and then opened through contentProvider. This image is being set in an imageView. So just before we write to the pipe we can decrypt on the fly and pass it to the app.

Comment: @nandeesh: Very helpful! I will make a point of running some experiments based on your code in the coming weeks. Many thanks!

Comment: @nandeesh: I had finally the time to check your app and to use it into my project, and it works really great so a big thanks to you. I have implemented it to pass byte array to an other application and it works fine. I have also found a way to use phone application with ACTION_VIEW, by getting the extension of the file and by using it with a MimeTypeMap and with the getMimeTypeFromExtension method. However, the opened file can be edited, so do you know if there is a way to get back this edited file?

Comment: i am not too sure, i guess its dependent on the third party app

Comment: Ok thanks, I will try to find a solution and let you inform of my result. Any idea will be appreciated.