# No Activity found to handle intent { act=android.intent.action.PICK dat=[null, /storage/emulated/0/WhatsApp/Media/WhatsApp Video]

Tags: android

Am getting the error like this when I pass some path which has been stored in database.

[image]

Actually I am using the below code

ArrayList path_list;

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
         uri = Uri.parse(path_list.get(2).toString());
        intent.setDataAndType(uri,"video/*");
        Log.e("URI",uri.toString());
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Open folder"),152);
```

So please suggest whether I can use same code or have to change anything in this.

Databasehelper class

```
  public ArrayList<String> getpaths()
{
    ArrayList<String> path_list = new ArrayList<String>();

    //hp = new HashMap();
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase("somePass");
    Cursor res =  db.rawQuery( "select * from Configuration", null );
    res.moveToFirst();

    while(res.isAfterLast() == false){
        path_list.add(res.getString(res.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_NAME_VIDEOPATH)));
        res.moveToNext();
    }
    return path_list;
}
```

after open folder to get the selected path

```
 String selectedMediaPath = null;
            if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
                selectedMediaPath = getPath(this, uri);
                Log.e("path", path_list.get(2).toString());
                Log.d("mediapath",selectedMediaPath);
            }
```

This is the getpath() method:

```
 @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
public static String getPath(final Context context, final Uri uri) {

    final boolean isKitKat = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT;

    // DocumentProvider
    if (isKitKat && DocumentsContract.isDocumentUri(context, uri)) {
        // ExternalStorageProvider
        if (isExternalStorageDocument(uri)) {
            final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
            final String[] split = docId.split(":");
            final String type = split[0];

            if ("primary".equalsIgnoreCase(type)) {
                return Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + split[1];
            }

            // TODO handle non-primary volumes
        }
        // DownloadsProvider
        else if (isDownloadsDocument(uri)) {

            final String id = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
            final Uri contentUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(
                    Uri.parse("content://downloads/public_downloads"), Long.valueOf(id));

            return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, null, null);
        }
        // MediaProvider
        else if (isMediaDocument(uri)) {
            final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
            final String[] split = docId.split(":");
            final String type = split[0];

            Uri contentUri = null;
            if ("image".equals(type)) {
                contentUri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
            } else if ("video".equals(type)) {
                contentUri = MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
            } else if ("audio".equals(type)) {
                contentUri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
            }

            final String selection = "_id=?";
            final String[] selectionArgs = new String[] {
                    split[1]
            };

            return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, selection, selectionArgs);
        }
    }
    // MediaStore (and general)
    else if ("content".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {
        return getDataColumn(context, uri, null, null);
    }
    // File
    else if ("file".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {
        return uri.getPath();
    }

    return null;
}

/**
 * Get the value of the data column for this Uri. This is useful for
 * MediaStore Uris, and other file-based ContentProviders.
 *
 * @param context The context.
 * @param uri The Uri to query.
 * @param selection (Optional) Filter used in the query.
 * @param selectionArgs (Optional) Selection arguments used in the query.
 * @return The value of the _data column, which is typically a file path.
 */
public static String getDataColumn(Context context, Uri uri, String selection,
                                   String[] selectionArgs) {

    Cursor cursor = null;
    final String column = "_data";
    final String[] projection = {
            column
    };

    try {
        cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs,
                null);
        if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            final int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(column);
            return cursor.getString(column_index);
        }
    } finally {
        if (cursor != null)
            cursor.close();
    }
    return null;
}


/**
 * @param uri The Uri to check.
 * @return Whether the Uri authority is ExternalStorageProvider.
 */
public static boolean isExternalStorageDocument(Uri uri) {
    return "com.android.externalstorage.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
}

/**
 * @param uri The Uri to check.
 * @return Whether the Uri authority is DownloadsProvider.
 */
public static boolean isDownloadsDocument(Uri uri) {
    return "com.android.providers.downloads.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
}

/**
 * @param uri The Uri to check.
 * @return Whether the Uri authority is MediaProvider.
 */
public static boolean isMediaDocument(Uri uri) {
    return "com.android.providers.media.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
}
```

Log file:

```
10-19 15:30:24.549 12482-12482/com.onnurinet.andriodstb E/URI: /storage/emulated/0/WhatsApp/Media/WhatsApp Video
```

10-19 15:30:34.031 12482-12482/com.onnurinet.andriodstb E/uri: content://media/external/video/media/36930
10-19 15:30:34.050 12482-12482/com.onnurinet.andriodstb E/path: /storage/sdcard1/videos
10-19 15:30:34.050 12482-12482/com.onnurinet.andriodstb D/mediapath: /storage/emulated/0/WhatsApp/Media/WhatsApp Video/VID-20161018-WA0001.3gp
10-19 15:30:34.069 12482-12482/com.onnurinet.andriodstb D/intent path_list: /storage/sdcard1/videos
10-19 15:30:34.128 12482-12482/com.onnurinet.andriodstb D/url: /storage/sdcard1/videos

please tell something I tried for two days.

Comment: Is there whatsapp installed in device?

Comment: yes it is there when i click it has to go to that gallery path where that whatsappvideo is there

Answer (score 3):

I think the error is very self explanatory. There isn't an app(actually activity) to handle the specific intent.
Use

```
if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {

    startAFR(intent);

}else{
    //Log no activity found
    //Inform user via toast/snackbar etc
}
```

Open Folder to pick a video file

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT); 
Uri uri = Uri.parse(...); 
intent.setDataAndType(uri, "video/*");   
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Open folder"));
```

Comment: It means no activity can handle your specific `Intent`

Comment: when i use your code nothing is happening no crashing no output

Comment: Yes, that would be the desired output if no app can handle the Intent. See edit.

Comment: instead of startAFR() can we use anything to open that URL

Comment: That would be `intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)` and `intent.setType("video/*"/*for video*/)` and then `intent.setData(Uri.parse(path_list.get(0).toString()));`

Comment: But still saying No Avtivity found exception

Comment: Did you replace `Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);` with simply `Intent intent = new Intent();`?

Comment: Yes I have done exactly like that but still same exception at startAFR();

Comment: In that path_list actually some path is there  "/storage/emulated/0/WhatsApp/Media/WhatsApp Video". this is that so when i click it has to open that gallery

Comment: Wait, you want to open that folder so as to pick a picture/video from it and return to your activity?

Comment: after open that folder i have to pass that video

Comment: it is aying no apps perform this action

Comment: actually my aim is in path_list one path is there when i click through an intent or some other thing it has to open that path i.e., in path_list. so that when i open i can able to select video and play

Comment: So is `path_list` a file or folder path?

Comment: it is a folder path

Comment: So once the gallery has opened the folder, what next? Do you need the file path of the selected video returned to your app or just played there?

Comment: Please suggest something even am unable to go to that path which has been stored in path_list

Comment: What is `path_list.get(2).toString());` when you log it?

Comment: actually its a array list so i gave some index for that

Comment: uri = Uri.parse(path_list.get(2).toString());
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, uri);
            intent.setDataAndType(uri,"video/*");
            Log.e("URI",uri.toString());
            startActivityForResult(intent,152);

Comment: What's the output?

Comment: its not opening directly that folder. it is showing all folders

Comment: The output of the log, a.k.a "/mnt/.../..."?

Comment: No, in log it is showing same path whatever in path_list.

Comment: actually it has to pick file from my path but it is picking file from all media videos in device

Comment: Just paste here the "/mnt.../" string from log. That's all i want

Comment: have you checked the log

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you are using ArrayList(path_list) you should get the values with it's index like `path_list.get(0).toString();`

```
 final Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
 intent.setData(Uri.parse(path_list.get(0).toString()));
 startActivityForResult(intent,152);
```

If you are having the problem still then try the below one

```
<activity android:name=".YourActivity">

    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <data android:scheme="file" />
    <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
    <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.mp4" />

</activity>
```

And still you don't have a solution? then please try the below one

[Open file securely with an external Android application without copying the file onto the external storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12386399/open-file-securely-with-an-external-android-application-without-copying-the-file)

Comment: I have edited my Answer with two of the possible sources to Fix your problem, let me know if you are having trouble with this.

Comment: No still same problem according to @ Elvis Chweya am unable to open the path stored in array list